# Animations not starting once in Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework

I use phaser 2.6.1.

I have created an animation. This works fine but sometimes the animation is not starting. I don't know why.

In `create()` function, I add animations for my spritesheet:

```
this.car = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX,500, 'car');
this.car.animations.add('mover',[0,1,2,3],1000, true);
this.car.fixedToCamera = true;
```

When overlap, I start the function to animate this:

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.car, this.borders, this.canMove, null, this);
```

This is my function:

```
},canMove: function(car, objet){
    if(crash == 0){
        crash = 1;
        _this.car.animations.play("mover");
                console.log("fire")
        setTimeout(function(){
            _this.car.animations.stop();
            _this.car.frame = 0;
            crash = 0;
        },1000)
    }
}
```

When the car overlaps a border, this function is triggered.

The `console.log()` is triggered but the animation suddenly is not starting. I can restart a lot of time my page and suddenly the animation is not starting even though the `console.log()` is triggered.

Comment: can you post ur code snippet?

Comment: post ur entire code here

Comment: ok i have add all the code

Comment: the animation is start on "canMove" function

Comment: I have already have this issue with other code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because i have first initialized my car with :

```
this.car = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX,500, 'car');
this.car.animations.add('mover',[0,1,2,3],1000, true);
this.car.fixedToCamera = true;
_this = this
```

After in my function i call directly my car with `_this`

I used `_this` because inside `setTimeout()`, `this` property is no equal of `this` of document

I dont know why but if i initialize first with `this` and after i call with `_this` this is not working fine. Also for resolve my issue i have starting with `_this` directly.

```
_this = this;
_this.car = game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX,500, 'car');
_this.car.animations.add('mover',[0,1,2,3],1000, true);
_this.car.fixedToCamera = true;
```